# Update list of records in ember-data model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am loading list of product in ember model.

```
products: this.store.findAll('products');
```

Now I have to add 1 property to each product and then it should save all models with only one network request.

I am updating property as below

```
product.set('reviewed', true);
```

I am looping through `model.products` and setting the property what is the best way to save all list of products at once.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing this, that I know of currently.

Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1849) tracking this.
A similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247414/ember-data-bulk-saves-to-server).

You will most likely want to find an addon that does something like this, or you could investigate doing it yourself by extending the adapter you currently use or creating a simple service with a queue you can push to and a save method with a custom request.

Here is a [comprehensive gist](https://gist.github.com/sheldonnbbaker/7330288) where the adapter is extended with some functionality with this.

Comment: Cool. I think then I will have to call $.ajax